# RSS Feed for bounties?

Tags: discussion, support, bounty, rss

Is there a feed available somewhere that tracks bounties offered? Apologies if this has been discussed and rejected elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, look for the RSS icon on that page

https://serverfault.com/feeds/featured

Comment: Odd. Firefox doesn't seem to reliably indicate feed presence, and the one time it did, I only got the normal site question feed.